# Nuxt prefetchLinks glitch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a project with nuxtjs, the bug is this: if I disable prefetchLinks you can see a glitch / flashing in the text when you move between pages (NuxtLink), but if I enable prefetchLinks the glitch happen when a NuxtLink enter to the viewport.

Steps to reproduce the bug (currently prefetchLinks is disabled):

Staging Link http://yummy-colours.netlify.app/

1. Click on any internal link
2. See the glitch / flashing only on text elements, images are ok

Video of the glitch: https://vimeo.com/541164342

**nuxt.config.js:**

```
export default {
  srcDir: 'src',
  router: {
    prefetchLinks: false,
  },
  render: {
    resourceHints: false,
  },
  target: 'static',
  ssr: false,
}
```

**Navigation NuxtLink example:**

```
<NuxtLink
  v-for="(item, index) in items"
  :key="index"
  :class="[$style.item]"
  :to="item.slug === 'home' ? `/` : `/${item.slug}/`"
>
  <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
</NuxtLink>
```

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: The problem is probably not located in the shared code but in the layout of the header.

Comment: The glitch is happening in all the text in the website, not just in the header :(

Comment: Try maybe removing the fancy animations that do not help troubleshooting here. Maybe inspecting with chrome devtools (animations). Have to admit that it happens pretty quickly ! :O